# JAVA Trouble printing the correct amount of grades that the user asked for using one dimenstional array and methodss

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

I'm basically asking the user to enter the amount of grades he would like to enter and those grades would be stored in an array. I would ask the user "Please enter the number of grades". If the user has entered '3' for example. Then the he would be asked to input data for 3 grades. A message would pring "Enter grade 1: " "Enter grade 2: " "Enter Grade 3: " etc. I didn't have any trouble writing the code but obviously it's not correct.

When I enter 3 for example for the number of grades, the program starts my printing "Enter Grade 0:" and then goes on to print 4 grades.  [image]

Here's my code:

I feel like I need to somehow involve the array length? Any help would greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `i <= numOfGrades` --> `i < numOfGrades`

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++)

Comment: @coco you should mark this as solved to avoid a million duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have i< numOfGrades since you are starting at 0. Also add 1 to i in the print statement to start at grade 1 :).

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++) {

        System.out.println("Enter grade " + (i+1) + ": ");

        mogrades[i] = NumberReader.readPositiveDouble(input, 
                    "Enter grade: ", "Invalid data entered");
```

I also agree with the other posters here. You should be using mogrades.length. This makes it clear to the reviewer that you are likely going to be working with the array, mogrades.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mogrades.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter grade " + (i+1) + ": ");

            mogrades[i] = NumberReader.readPositiveDouble(input, 
                        "Enter grade: ", "Invalid data entered");
```

Comment: @coco You should mark this as solved to avoid more duplicate responses.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. :) Is there a way I can change my for loop format so that the program can start off by Printing "Enter Grade 1: " instead of starting off by printing "Enter grade 0"?

Comment: Mark it means accepting the answer right? (I'm fairly new here sorry)

Comment: Yes. Modified it accordingly!

Comment: Thank you so much. Really helped me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes are from 0 to size - 1. When `i` equals to `numOfGrades` in the loop you are out of the array. Change `i <= numOfGrades` to `i < numOfGrades` or better to `i < mogrades.length`

```
for (int i = 0; i < mogrades.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter grade " + i + ": ");
    mogrades[i] = NumberReader.readPositiveDouble(input, "Enter grade: ", "Invalid data entered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `numOfGrades` slots with your array . So, this is `0,1...numOfGrades-1`. However, you loop upto `numOfGrades` due to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfGrades; i++)
```

You should use

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++)
```

to not write beyond the end of your array.